# How to install tbb_dedug.dll in VS2010 Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, intel, visual-c++-2010

I am trying to run openCV code with VS2010 Windows 7 Ultimate cpu intel CORE i3 but it shows the following error:

> **The program can't start because tbb_dubug.dll is missing from your computer**

I downloaded Intel TBB 4.0 and I copied all files from folder `tbb40_233oss/bin/intel64/vc10` to `opencv/build/common/tbb/intel64/vc10`, But when I run my code it shows the same error. So, I copied tbb_debug.dll to the Debug folder in my Project, But when I run my code it shows the error

> **TestHist\Debug\tbb_debug.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.**

How do I install tbb_dedug.dll in VS2010 Windows 7 ?

Comment: Don't try to use a 64-bit version of a DLL with a 32-bit build of your program.  Download the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to download the files from intel directly. Find them with google then copy the `tbb_debug.dll` in the same directory where your executable is.